# Can I inject meta tags via javascript to html? And is there any effect when I do that?

Tags: javascript, html, web, cors

## Problem

I am a ethical hacker and I am currently working on a challenge. I cannot disclose the challenge name right now.
There is a website vulnerable to `HTML Injection` and I can inject `meta` tags in there. Can I disable the CORS via that?

### Meta tag payload

`<META HTTP-EQUIV=Access-Control-Allow-Origin CONTENT=*>`
I tried above payload and it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Support for meta elements injected with JS very much depends on which meta element and what client is consuming it.

`HTTP-EQUIV` only supports a [*very* limited subset of HTTP headers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-meta-http-equiv) which don't include any defined by the CORS specification (which makes support for it via JS injection moot).